# Send file from Server to Client java with Spring and Rest web service

Tags: java, spring, file, rest, file-io

I have to send file from Server (from its file system) to Cliente (another pc and store file in a particularly folder) through java code and Rest web service. These files can be even **120MB**.
I used `MultipartFile` to upload file from my web page but I don't know how to download from the client.
It would be good the possibility to use a REST web service that returns both file and message with result of method (true or false if there was an error).
Do you have an idea?
At the moment I use this code in server:

and the best way would be

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/oldmethod", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Response getAcquisition(@RequestParam(value="path", defaultValue="/home") String path){
    File file;
    try {
        file = matlabClientServices.getFile(path);

        if (file.exists()){

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);

            byte[]out=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            return new Response(true, true, out, null);
        }
        else 
            return new Response(false, false, "File doesn't exist!", null);         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in MatlabClientControllerImpl::getAcquisition :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
        return new Response(false, false, "Error during file retrieving!", errorResponse);
    }       
}
```

but to the client the code below doesn't work:

```
public Response getFileTest(@RequestParam(value="path", defaultValue="/home") String path){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Response response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8086/ATS/client/file/oldmethod/?path={path}", Response.class, path);
        if (response.isStatus() && response.isSuccess()){
                try {
                    Files.write(Paths.get("PROVIAMOCI.txt"),org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(response.getResult().toString()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

it writes the byte[] characters and not the original text

Comment: What kind of issue gives to you?some error ...

Comment: Yes I can't retrieve the original fle

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding FileSystemResource used for get the file system using file system URI but it is not over the HTTP. Using FileSystemResource you can access files from your local machine to local accessible file system and from server to your server accesiable file system. But could not access from local to server file system.

Comment: ok, my problem is how to receive, for example I update with other method to upload files

Comment: send from sever side byte array of file and receive from client side as byte array stream and store than byte array stream somewhere at client side

Comment: like the above getAcquisition method?

Comment: I updated main post, but on the client how can I write the file in local directory?

Comment: Using FileOutputStream .. you can write byte array on file there are lot of example available to refer.

Comment: I can not copy the original file content, it copies the byte[] characters